# Azure custom policyto turn on hybrid license for sql db in conflict status

Tags: azure

I am creating a custom policy to enable hybrid pricing on a SQL database if it is NOT enabled.  I have it working with AUDIT mode - see policy below - the below policy is working..it finds the two databases not in compliance.  However, when I try to add the append action I get 2 conflicts on the two databases not having hybrid option chosen - I was expecting and hoping the policy would enable hybrid mode on those two databases.  The code for the 2nd policy is also below.

```
` "properties": {
    "displayName": "Audit SQL DB without Hybrid Licensing",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "description": "Generate audit record if SQL DB is not configured for hybrid license",
    "metadata": {
      "category": "SQL",
      "createdBy": "5a53d124-483a-4726-9b6f-bd9fa5e56cf3",
      "createdOn": "2020-12-11T19:52:20.1852612Z",
      "updatedBy": "5a53d124-483a-4726-9b6f-bd9fa5e56cf3",
      "updatedOn": "2020-12-23T17:36:10.6538643Z"
    },
    "parameters": {},
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.SQL/servers/databases"
          },
          {
            "field": "kind",
            "contains": "vcore"
          },
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/licenseType",
            "notEquals": "BasePrice"
          },
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/sku.name",
            "notEquals": "ElasticPool"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "audit"
      }
    }
  },
`
```

2nd policy not working but creates 2 conflicts

```
    {
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.SQL/servers/databases"
        },
        {
          "field": "kind",
          "contains": "vcore"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/licenseType",
          "notEquals": "BasePrice"
        },
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/sku.name",
          "notEquals": "ElasticPool"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "append",
      "details": [
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/licenseType",
          "value": "BasePrice"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```